# Why do inline-block divs align unevenly with each other?

Tags: html, css

How can I position two `inline-block` `div`s with `height` attributes on the same row?

Expected:

`#legend` and `#container` should be on the same row.

Actual:

`#legend` is positioned much after the `#container`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76wLxnkz/)

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#legend {
  height: 500px;
  border: solid red;
}

#container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="legend">
  <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

On the other hand, if we don't put a `height` attribute, it [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/nx7jLaar/).

Comment: Use **display:inline-flex** to the body and see it will work

Comment: In this case, you should specify a vertical-align, like `div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}`

Comment: @Kangouroops But what is the reason for the weird behaviour when `vertical-align` is missing?

Comment: @Utku Well, the default `vertical-align;` value is baseline, but you have text only in one of your div, you can test but writing something in your second div, it will works then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An initial setting on inline-level elements is `vertical-align: baseline`. This means that elements such as `span`, `textarea` and `img`, whose default `display` value is `inline`, will align themselves to the baseline of the container.

> [***baseline***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography))
>
> The line upon which most letters "sit" and below which descenders extend.
>
> [image]
>
> <sup>Source: [Wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography))</sup>

In your question, you have set the divs to `display: inline-block`. This activates baseline alignment, and the boxes align vertically to each others' baseline. That's what you're seeing.

You can resolve the problem by overriding the default value on `vertical-align`. Try this:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;  /* new */
}

#legend {
  height: 500px;
  border: solid red;
}

#container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="legend">
  <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

OR, just put some text in the empty div (although `vertical-align` may still come in handy to fully even out the alignment).

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#legend {
  height: 500px;
  border: solid red;
}

#container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="legend">
  <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
<div id="container">text text text</div>
```

Comment: Btw why is the effect of `vertical-align: top`, `vertical-align: middle` and `vertical-align: bottom` is the same?

Comment: Because the height of the two divs is the same. If they had different heights, you would see the difference.